# HQL many to many between 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, many-to-many, hql

I have 3 tables :

**User** ->>- many to many ->>- **Userapp** ->>- many to many ->>- **Application**

**User** have :

- userId
- userName

**UserApp** :

- userId
- applicationId

**Applicaiton** :

- applicationId
- applicaitonName

I didn't succeed in creating a HQL query which returns every Application of one specific user.

My HQL :

```
select a.userId, a.userName from Application b join b.userId a where b.userId = 1
```

Simplify query i would like to do : `from Application WHERE Userapp.userID = 1`

could you help me please :) ?

EDIT :

My tools :

- Netbean 8.x
- Hibernate plugin

Second error : `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Userapp is not mapped`

When i create hibernate mapping files and POJOs from database it creates me 2 objects : User and Application. But not the associative table "Userapp"

My hibernate.reveng.xml :

```
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <schema-selection match-catalog="allin"/>
  <table-filter match-name="user"/>
  <table-filter match-name="application"/>
  <table-filter match-name="userapp"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

Regards

Comment: I think it should be `User 1--* UserApp *--1 Application` ;)

Comment: I correct it just after ;) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query should be like this:

```
SELECT a.applicaitonName
FROM User u
    LEFT JOIN UserApp ua ON u.userId= ua.userId
    LEFT JOIN Application a On ua.applicationId= a.applicationId
WHERE
    u.userName = ?
```

or

```
SELECT a.applicaitonName
FROM UserApp ua
    LEFT JOIN Application a On ua.applicationId= a.applicationId
WHERE
    ua.userId = ?
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

second problem is with the table "Userapp" ...

"Userapp is not mapped". 

I use Netbean with hibernate, so when i create POJO files that just create 2 objects (User and Applicaitons). The association "Userapp" table is not create ... i have to do manually ?

Edit : When i create hibernate.revenge.xml i choose my 3 tables (i edit it on the post)

Comment: @ValentinGarreau for a new question ask a new question, it will make more sense ;).